# Error in a c# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

This code takes an array of `char` as parameter and return an array that contains each word of the array. No word can contain spaces. Might need some help as I get an error on `tab[i][j] = str[counter]`, but I think you can tell what I want it to do.

```
public static char[][] split_string(char[] str)
{
    char[][] tab = new char[20][];
    int x = 1;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
        {
            if (str[i] != ' ')
            {
                tab[i][j] = str[counter];
            }
            else
            {
                counter++;
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Comment: Could you at least try to format your code? See [ask].

Comment: What specific error are you getting? I suspect you need to check for both spaces and empty values in your if statement as the empty spaces are passing.

Comment: I did now. Sorry about this

Comment: I'm getting this error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in array.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You never initialize your inner array. You have an array of 20 char arrays, but each of those *inner* arrays is null. Also, the structure of your loops is pretty nonsensical.

Comment: As for the arrays, think of it this way: you initialized `tab` with `new char[20][]`. Well now, `tab[0]` is a `char[]` and that `char[]` has not been initialized. It is null. Thus, when you try to use `tab[0][0]`, the second indexer is attempting to index a null array. For your loops, I"m pretty sure you mostly want your inner loop. Indexing`tab` with `i` and `j` makes no sense. Pretty sure you want to use `counter` instead of `i`, but you're also going to have to keep track of what character you are on in your current word in additional variable, for your second index.

Comment: @JGreenwell If I were to guess I would say it's this: http://imgur.com/gallery/gBCsyN7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### The immediate problem

When you declare `char[][] tab = new char[20][];`

you are creating an array of arrays of char, of size 20. That is an array that has 20 elements that are arrays of char, each one of those 20 arrays will be set to null.

So, when you try to do `tab[i][j] = str[counter];` you are trying to set the element on the index 'j´ of the array on the index 'i' of the array tabs, but the array on the index 'i' of the array 'tabs' is null (as all the other arrays in the array 'tabs' are). So you get a `NullReferenceException`.

---

In general, if you get a `NullReferenceException` it means that some reference is null, duh. It probably means you forgot to initilize something... You wil be pointed to where it happened, and it would be your work to figure out what was null there, why is it null, question yourself if it is right that it is null... if it is not, then fix it by intializing the variable. If it is, then check for null and do the appropiate thing for that case.

---

In your particular case, it shouldn't be null. So you have to initilize it. Initialize what? The array that you will be filling. Remember that when you said `new char[20][];` you created an array of 20 arrays that are set to be null, but you don't want them to be null, but arrays.

So a simple `tab[i] = new char[str.Length];` befor the inner loop will solve the immediate problem.

---

### The other problem

Ok, but you will face another problem once that one is fixed. You see, you are creating an array of 20 elements. But the array you get on the parameter `str` maybe longer. So - when that happens - you will get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` as you try to write beyond the element of index 19 of your array.

And honestly... It is hard to infer from the code what you are trying to do.

---

### What you are trying to do

Guessing from the signature of the method, I guess you want to take an array of chars and return and array of arrays of chars, where wach array contains a word.

And for some mysterious reasons you are not using `string`. If I'm right, the method that you should be using is [`string.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

These are my guesses for the mysterious reasons:

- You are victim of a *sadict* teacher that wants you to not use string, List or anything like that.
- You need to do interop with some system that only understand arrays of chars.
- You used the wrong language tag, and this is a C question instead of a C# one.

Ok, let's assume it is the interop case. You can do this:

1) Create a new array from the char array:

```
new string(str)
```

2) Call split on it:

```
(new string(str)).Split(' ')
```

3) Convert each returned string into a char array:

```
from string s in (new string(str)).Split(' ') select s.ToCharArray()
```

4) Conver the resulting collection to an array:

```
(from string s in (new string(str)).Split(' ') select s.ToCharArray()).ToArray();
```

5) wrap it on a method:

```
public static char[][] split_string(char[] str)
{
    return (from string s in (new string(str)).Split(' ') select s.ToCharArray()).ToArray();
}
```

Ok, you can do it without LINQ:

```
public static char[][] split_string(char[] str)
{
    var list = new List<char[]>();
    foreach (string s in (new string(str)).Split(' '))
    {
        list.Add(s.ToCharArray());
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

But that is all trash, this is what you should be doing:

1) Accept an string:

```
public static char[][] split_string(string str)
{
    var list = new List<char[]>();
    foreach (string s in str.Split(' '))
    {
        list.Add(s.ToCharArray());
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

2) return using string:

```
public static string[] split_string(string str)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    foreach (string s in str.Split(' '))
    {
        list.Add(s);
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

3) get rid of the stuffing:

```
public static string[] split_string(string str)
{
    return str.Split(' ');
}
```

4) Why did you declare a method anyway?

```
// ...puff...
```